# check if a string matches with a given string from a certain position onwards javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

```js
var obj2 = [{
  "name": "4134",
  "calls": [

  ]
}]

    var obj3 = [{ Channel: 'SIP/4134-0004462a',
        State: 'Up',
        Accountcode: '7013658596'},
      { Channel: 'SIP/4334-sa',
        State: 'Up',
        Accountcode: '07717754702',
      }]


var channelArr = [];
const Channels = obj3.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
  obj2.forEach((item)=>{
    if(curVal.Channel.includes('SIP') &&  item.name == curVal.Channel.slice(4,8).toString()){
      item.calls.push({'MobileNo':curVal.Accountcode,'Status': curVal.State})
    }
  })
  return obj2;
}, [])

console.log(obj2);
```

The output of the above code is

```
[
  {
    "name": "4134",
    "calls": [
      {
        "MobileNo": "7013658596",
        "Status": "Up"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code takes `"name": "4134"` from obj2 and `Channel: 'SIP/4134-0004462a` from obj3. It then checks if 4134 from obj2 exists in the value `'SIP/4134-0004462a'` from obj3 using the code `curVal.Channel.includes('SIP') &&  item.name == curVal.Channel.slice(4,8).toString()` . If the value exists then it pushes the `MobileNo` and `AccountCode` from that particular object and pushes it into the calls array of obj2.
Since `Channel: 'SIP/4134-0004462a` is very predictable here as if the value contains `SIP` and `slice(4,8)` position then `4134` matches perfectly. But what if instead of `4134` I have to match a value like `"name" : "4134556"` ? In this case it won't work as `4134556` won't match with `'SIP/4134556-0004462a` if I use `slice(4,8)` on obj3. 
I want a solution such that it takes the value of name key from obj2 and takes the value of Channel key from obj3 and check if the value from obj2 exists in Channel value starting from position 4 (i.e after SIP/ ) I don't want to set a limit like `splice(4,8)`, instead it should be something dynamic which can match any digit of name with the Channel starting from position 4 in the Channel value (expecting something like `splice(start from 4th position and match the next digits for a match)` ). This will let me match the numbers perfectly even if they have any number of digits.

What I tried as a temporary solution :

```
if(curVal.Channel.includes('SIP') && curVal.Channel.includes(item.name))
```

but this gives me wrong result at `Channel : SIP/3422-0413462a` from obj3 will also match with `name : 4134` from obj2 as it contains the number 4134 at some other position and this is not the desired result.

How do I do it such that name from obj2 is matched with Channel of obj3 starting from the 4th position i.e after `SIP/` and check if there's a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.startsWith(searchString, position)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```js
console.log('SIP/4134556-0004462a'.startsWith('4134556', 4)); // true
```

The `position` parameter allows to specify where in the haystack you want to search for the needle (in your case position `4`).

This might give you another issue, as this will also evaluate to true:

```
'SIP/4134556-0004462a'.startsWith('4134', 4); // true
```

If this is not what you want (i.e. you want the value to be followed by the `-` separator), you have to add the separator to your search string:

```
'SIP/4134556-0004462a'.startsWith('4134' + '-', 4) // false
```

Comment: curVal.Channel.startsWith(item.name,4) is this statement correct in reference to my code?

Comment: wow your updated answer is perfect it will always give correct results in my case

Answer (score 1):

You can use name length as the second parameter to slice. you don't need regex here mate :)

**Something like this**

```
curVal.Channel.slice(4,4+item.name.length)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
var obj2 = [{
  "name": "4134123",
  "calls": [

  ]
}]

    var obj3 = [{ Channel: 'SIP/4134123-0004462a',
        State: 'Up',
        Accountcode: '7013658596'},
      { Channel: 'SIP/4334-sa',
        State: 'Up',
        Accountcode: '07717754702',
      }]


var channelArr = [];
const Channels = obj3.reduce((acc, curVal) => {
  obj2.forEach((item)=>{
    if(curVal.Channel.includes('SIP') &&  item.name == curVal.Channel.slice(4,4+item.name.length).toString()){
      item.calls.push({'MobileNo':curVal.Accountcode,'Status': curVal.State})
    }
  })
  return obj2;
}, [])

console.log(obj2);
```

Comment: I appreciate this solution too

Answer (score 1):

Get Sub string of `Channel` from position `4` to end and check name is exist in that substring or not

```js
var channel = "SIP/4134123-0004462a"; //your channel name
console.log(channel.substring(4).includes("4134123")); //your name
```